# New background according to url

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible i'm certain it is, to change a background image according to the url?

For example www.myurl.co.uk/halloween/

if url contains /halloween/ 
then 
body {background:url(/images/newbackground.jpg)}

I think I have done this before but for the life of me I can't remember how to do it.

jQuery preferred?

Comment: does url even goes like www.myurl.co.uk/halloween/product123

Comment: jQuery isn't necessary. You can just use a simple script to pull out and insert that keyword into a background value `window.onload` (using `window.addEventListener`, of course).

Comment: `document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(/bg/img/path/' + type + ')';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<script>

    var currentUrl = document.URL;

    if(currentUrl == 'www.myurl.co.uk/halloween/')
      document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(/images/newbackground.jpg)';
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("halloween") > -1) {
       alert("your url contains the name halloween");
       $("body").css('background', 'url("images/newbackground.jpg")');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This snippet might do the trick for you:

```
if(window.location.indexOf("halloween") != -1) {
  $("body").css('background', 'url(imgs/halloween.png)');
}
```

It looks for the string "halloween" in the current url, and if it's found anywhere in there, the body background is set to "imgs/halloween.png".

Comment: `$("body").css('background', 'url("imgs/halloween.png")')` is more correct

Comment: `$("body").css('background-image', 'url("imgs/halloween.png")')` is even more correct :)

Comment: There is a small difference ... not mantioning `url` is a syntax disrespecting ... `background` and `background-image` are both correct depending what we want or don't want to set. `backround:` is preferable because we can set all the properties of the background at once and the guy mentioned in his question `background:`  ... not `background image:` ;)

Answer (score 2):

jQuery adds unnecessary overhead for this. Given a map of keywords to images:

```
var images = {
    'halloween' : '/images/newbackground.jpg',
    'christmas' : '/images/xmasbackground.jpg'
};
```

You can do this:

```
var url = document.location.href,
    elem = document.getElementById('elementThatYouWantToStyle');

for (var keyword in images){
    if (images.hasOwnProperty(keyword) && url.indexOf(keyword) !== -1) {
        elem.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + encodeURI(images[keyword]) + ')';
    }
}
```

And now, with a fully fledged (and [thankfully debugged](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13001333/)) functional form:

```
var images = {
    'halloween': 'http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/img/dexter.png',
    'christmas': 'http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/img/mandark.png'
};

function setBG(el, map, url) {
    if (!el || !map) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        url = url || document.location.href;
        /* means you can pass an element's `id` or a reference to the node itself */
        el = el.nodeType == 1 ? el : document.getElementById(el);
        for (var keyword in map) {
            if (map.hasOwnProperty(keyword) && url.indexOf(keyword) !== -1) {
                el.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + map[keyword] + ')';
            }
        }
    }
}

setBG('one', images, 'http://some.domain.com/with/halloween.jpg');
setBG(document.getElementById('two'), images, 'http://some.domain.com/with/christmas.jpg');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/VsZ4f/5/).

Comment: Nice. Probably would load faster too. Now, wouldn't that need to run on page load? (Just saying. It could occur after the `elem` as well, of course.)

Comment: Well, yes. Yes, it would...but I was going to abstract it out to a generic function and let the 'reader' address the on page-load aspect.

Answer (score 0):

maybee you add a class to the body for every page via jQuery, e.g. for /halloween/:
    $("body").addClass("halloween");

Then in Css:
    body.halloween {
    /* custom bg */
    }

You could make all links orange then,too:
    body.halloween a {color:orange;}

Comment: In Combination with the answer above, you can extract the last part of the url and let the class get generated automatically.

Comment: Wow! this has caused quite a stir! Many many options. here is the background to this question, I run an eCommerce site on Opencart, I have done several mods, and come up with an idea of changing the back depending on the category to give it a bit of a more themed feel, so going on all these options I might look at writing a full plugin for the site to allow this to happen in the category creation section of the admin area!

Answer (score 0):

Include code below in script tags -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var path = window.location.href.split("/");
    if (path.length > 2) {
       if(a[2] == "halloween" ) { 
           $('body').css({background : 'url(/images/newbackground.jpg)' });
       }
       else if(a[2] == "something_else") {
           $('body').css({background : 'url(/images/something_else.jpg)' });
       }
       //more else if for other images
    }

});
```