# Why does el.style.backgroundImage not work in this functional context?

Tags: javascript

I wrote an answer for this question: [New background according to url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000944/new-background-according-to-url), the code I posted in my answer was to check a URL for the presence of a particular string and, if it was there, change the background-image of a given element.

So! Me being me, I thought I'd try and avoid jQuery and go for a more traditional vanilla JavaScript approach with the following:

```
var images = {
    'halloween' : '/images/newbackground.jpg',
    'christmas' : '/images/xmasbackground.jpg'
};

var url = document.location.href,
    elem = document.getElementById('elementThatYouWantToStyle');

for (var keyword in images){
    if (images.hasOwnProperty(keyword) && url.indexOf(keyword) !== -1) {
        elem.style.backgroundImage = images[keyword];
    }
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13001019/82548).

Which I then thought I'd convert to a functional approach, so it became this:

```
var images = {
    'halloween': 'http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/img/dexter.png',
    'christmas': 'http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/img/mandark.png'
};

function setBG(el, map, url) {
    if (!el || !map) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var url = url || document.location.href,
            el = el.nodeType == 1 ? el : document.getElementById(el);
        for (var keyword in map) {
            if (map.hasOwnProperty(keyword) && url.indexOf(keyword) !== -1) {
                el.style.backgroundImage = encodeURIComponent(map[keyword]);
            }
        }
    }
}

setBG('one', images, 'http://some.domain.com/with/halloween.jpg');
setBG(document.getElementById('two'), images, 'http://some.domain.com/with/christmas.jpg');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/VsZ4f/1/).

Now, if I add a `console.log()` to the `if` assessment within the `for...in` loop it shows that we're getting into the loop, and the console [suggests that I have an accurate reference to the DOM node, the images object, the URL (as passed into the function) and am getting the correct value from the object](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/VsZ4f/2/).

The following line, however, in which I attempt to set the `el.style.backgroundImage` property, does *not* work (this is true whether or not I wrap the `map[keyword]` in the `encodeURIComponent()` or not albeit I've linked only to the attempt in which I *did*. So: what's the obvious flaw in my logic? Why is `el.style.backgroundImage` not being set?

(Incidentally JS Lint, at JS Fiddle, *seems* happy with it (other than the redefinition of existing variables (`url` and `el`) done in order to have a fall-back/default).

Comment: You know how, *sometimes*, you just *know* you've overlooked something in your sleep-deprived and addled state? =|

Comment: Also, as apparently the "re-declaring" of `var`s seems to throw off even some experienced programmers, I've complemented my answer with yet another paragraph about that and a link to [JavaScript Scoping and Hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting) - a really awesome read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are declaring a local variable `url` with `var url` that already defined as an argument `url` and you also need to use the form `url(http:/xxxx)`.

Change to this (removed `var` in front of `url` and added the `url()` around the url):

```
function setBG(el, map, url) {
    if (!el || !map) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        url = url || document.location.href;
        el = el.nodeType == 1 ? el : document.getElementById(el);
        for (var keyword in map) {
            if (map.hasOwnProperty(keyword) && url.indexOf(keyword) !== -1) {
                el.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + map[keyword] + ')';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @DavidThomas - I removed the` `var` in front of `var url` and I added `url()` around the actual URL for the style value.

Comment: Agh! I *knew* it'd be something silly and scope-related...thank you kindly, +1 and an impending acceptance coming your way! Thanks =)

Comment: The extra `var` declaration makes absolutely no difference. And not to be cranky but I was the first one to address the real issue & provide an working fiddle.

Comment: Actually [that seems to be true](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/VsZ4f/5/) (which surprises me, about the `var`, *why* doesn't it make a difference..?)

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - One involves Homer Simpson. (And I think you're right about `var`.)

Comment: Because the `var` keyword simply tells the interpreter that the variable belongs to that scope. Re-declaring a var that is already declared in the same scope makes no difference.

Comment: ps. The version with `encodeURIComponent` returns a 404 when applied on my fiddle, hence I removed it from my answer.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - Appears you're right about `var` (at least in Chrome): http://jsfiddle.net/5unHn/

Comment: Why redeclare a variable that is already declared?  It isn't required and is misleading in the code.

Comment: There's no reason indeed, but it is not an error per se. C'mon guys, you're all high reps, you know better that function's arguments are already declared variables inside the function body and re-declaring variables in the same scope has no effect in JS.

Comment: @Fabricio: yeah, I discovered that for myself also, when playing. And, my apologies for accepting this answer rather than yours, but jfriend *did* identify an error *and* the issue of execrable (and redundant) practice.

Comment: No problem @DavidThomas, I've just run into this issue myself not long ago so I felt like posting a reply as no one had until then. Well off-topic, but did this work with `encodeURIComponent`? May remove it from this answer for completeness if it doesn't, as it did not work for me.

Answer (score 5):

An URL is not a valid `backgroundImage` value unless you wrap it in a `url()`.

```
el.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + map[keyword] + ')';
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/VsZ4f/3/)

---

Also, you should not [`encodeURIcomponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) the whole URL, otherwise it will encode even the protocol's `:` and the `/`'s, resulting in a 404 as (due to the now lack of protocol) being interpreted as a relative URL:

> GET http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/http%3A%2F%2Fdavidrhysthomas.co.uk%2Fimg%2Fdexter.png 404 (Not Found)

Instead, to more safely encode a full URI you can use [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI):

```
el.style.backgroundImage = 'url("' + encodeURI(map[keyword]) + '")';
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/VsZ4f/8/)

**Note:** MDN mentions that `encodeURI` may not work as expected in different browsers with GET requests, that is, URLs including query strings. I couldn't reproduce that problem though.

---

Also as noted by @jfriend00, the `var` keyword before `url` is unnecessary, as it already belongs to the function scope due to being declared as a *formal parameter*.  Read more: [JavaScript Scoping and Hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting)

Comment: Moving the conversation over to your answer. And no, it didn't; that's what I meant by 'I discovered that for myself also, when playing.' Though the subject of that sentence wasn't clear; I found, as did Jared (in the other comment thread) that it returns a `404`. So I removed it.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the confirmation. Guess I'll add a paragraph about that for the sake of completeness.

Comment: @DavidThomas Added a paragraph about `encodeURIComponent` vs `encodeURI`, which may be useful for your function.